# Why can CNN model recognize characters in images without character segments?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

I have CNN:

[image]

Why is it able to recognize this image?

[image]

Without any text segmentation? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a classification layer, your model has 4 different classifiers and in the training phase, each classifier model learns somehow where to look and classify the characters separately. Of course, this is just a hypothesis on your question. I can give more information if I learn your loss function and target shape